# Is Angular rendered client side or server side?

Tags: angular

I've thought Angular framework is rendered client side but after reading [this](https://www.rishabhsoft.com/blog/reactjs-vs-angularjs) article, I couldn't realize which part of Angular application is rendered in server side. I searched and read but I couldn't find out when an Angular application is built and served trough some web server like Nginx, How is rendered in server side?

Comment: you should check official docs, everything is clearly mentioned. Do some research and then put a question in `SO`.

Comment: I read and found out that Angular not server side and angular universal is. But in referenced article, author said Angular is server side just like react. I thought maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 6):

A normal Angular application executes in the browser, rendering pages in the DOM in response to user actions. **Angular Universal** executes on the server, generating static application pages that later get bootstrapped on the client. This means that the application generally renders more quickly, giving users a chance to view the application layout before it becomes fully interactive.

[sourced from here](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

It can rendered in both the ways.

1. SSR: Server-Side Rendering - rendering a client-side or universal app to HTML on the server
2. CSR: Client-Side Rendering - rendering an app in a browser, generally using the DOM.

[Rendering on the Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web)

Answer (score 3):

The term "Rendering" is used quite misleading in the article you mention. You need to differentiate between the "build"-stage, where your JavaScript/Typescript/JSX is compiled and the "real" Rendering-stage, where nodes in the DOM are created and modified.

The build-stage might be on the server, on your CI-Server or even locally (e.g. your run `ng build`). These artifacts are then usually deployed on some http Server, where they are served. The application is then rendered in the browser. Rendering in the sense that the JavaScript is executed and creates/modifies DOM-Nodes.

Some Frameworks like Angular also support Prerendering on the server. This means, that the initial DOM is served as HTML instead of JavaScript to improve startup time. After this initial Prendering, everything else is done in the browser again.

Btw, the mentioned AngularJS did not have any build-stage.

Comment: Web crawlers won't be able to see the contents of a site built in Angular?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew It depends. Web crawlers used to fetch and evaluate only the HTML, but modern crawlers like Googles Crawler are able to evaluate JavaScript-Applications and therefore find content created by JavaScript. There is currently still some crawling speed penalty for JavaScript Applications though. See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics

Answer (score 1):

The article you reference is talking about AngularJS (https://angularjs.org/), not to be confused with Angular (https://angular.io/). AngularJS refers to version `1.x` whilst Angular is from version `2.x` and onwards. You can consider them as two completely different frameworks.

Angular is a client side framework, but with tools such as Angular Universal (https://angular.io/guide/universal), you can pre-render it on the server

Comment: Thank you for response, at first chart of article, author considers Anularjs as a client side but Angular and react as a server side rendering.

Comment: That would be incorrect. By default Angular is *not* rendered on the server side. It can be if you use a tool like angular universal